# jQuery File Tree - Detecting when folder is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the example shown below to add a jQuery file tree to my website:

https://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree

I can use it no problem to trigger an event when a file is clicked on as the demo shows but I can't seem to figure out how to detect when a folder is selected. I want to be able to determine which directory is currently selected at any point.

Now I have looked at the question asked here and tried what was suggested but my dire function is never fired (I never see my alert that I set up):

[Jquery File Tree - how to return folder name on folder click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000991/jquery-file-tree-how-to-return-folder-name-on-folder-click)

Here is my index.html which includes the jquery call at the beginning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>jQuery File Tree Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        BODY,
        HTML {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        BODY {
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            background: #EEE;
            padding: 15px;
        }

        H1 {
            font-family: Georgia, serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        H2 {
            font-family: Georgia, serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
        }

        .example {
            float: left;
            margin: 15px;
        }

        .demo {
            width: 200px;
            height: 400px;
            border-top: solid 1px #BBB;
            border-left: solid 1px #BBB;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #FFF;
            border-right: solid 1px #FFF;
            background: #FFF;
            overflow: scroll;
            padding: 5px;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqueryFileTree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jqueryFileTree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready( function() {
$('#fileTreeDemo_1').fileTree({ root: 'C:/wamp/www/uploads/', script: 'connectors/jqueryFileTree.php' }, function(file) {
    // do something when a file is clicked
    alert(file);
}, function(dire){
    // do something when a dir is clicked
    alert(dire);
});
});

    </script>

</head>

<body>


    <div class="example">
        <h2>Files</h2>
        <div id="fileTreeDemo_1" class="demo"></div>
    </div>



</body>
```

The main function of this being

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#fileTreeDemo_1').fileTree({ root: 'C:/wamp/www/uploads/', script: 'connectors/jqueryFileTree.php' }, function(file) {
// do something when a file is clicked
alert(file);
}, function(dire){
// do something when a dir is clicked
alert(dire);
});
});
```

Notice how I did set up the function(dire) part as the other SO question suggested. Am I missing something?

The js file:

```
if(jQuery) (function($){

$.extend($.fn, {
    fileTree: function(o, h, dire) {
        // Defaults
        if( !o ) var o = {};
        if( o.root == undefined ) o.root = '/';
        if( o.script == undefined ) o.script = 'jqueryFileTree.php';
        if( o.folderEvent == undefined ) o.folderEvent = 'click';
        if( o.expandSpeed == undefined ) o.expandSpeed= 500;
        if( o.collapseSpeed == undefined ) o.collapseSpeed= 500;
        if( o.expandEasing == undefined ) o.expandEasing = null;
        if( o.collapseEasing == undefined ) o.collapseEasing = null;
        if( o.multiFolder == undefined ) o.multiFolder = true;
        if( o.loadMessage == undefined ) o.loadMessage = 'Loading...';

        $(this).each( function() {

            function showTree(c, t) {
                $(c).addClass('wait');
                $(".jqueryFileTree.start").remove();
                $.post(o.script, { dir: t }, function(data) {
                    $(c).find('.start').html('');
                    $(c).removeClass('wait').append(data);
                    if( o.root == t ) $(c).find('UL:hidden').show(); else $(c).find('UL:hidden').slideDown({ duration: o.expandSpeed, easing: o.expandEasing });
                    bindTree(c);
                });
            }

            function bindTree(t) {
                $(t).find('LI A').bind(o.folderEvent, function() {
                    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('directory') ) {
                        if( $(this).parent().hasClass('collapsed') ) {
                            dire($(this).attr('rel'));
                            // Expand
                            if( !o.multiFolder ) {
                                $(this).parent().parent().find('UL').slideUp({ duration: o.collapseSpeed, easing: o.collapseEasing });
                                $(this).parent().parent().find('LI.directory').removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed');
                            }
                            $(this).parent().find('UL').remove(); // cleanup
                            showTree( $(this).parent(), escape($(this).attr('rel').match( /.*\// )) );
                            $(this).parent().removeClass('collapsed').addClass('expanded');
                        } else {
                            // Collapse
                            $(this).parent().find('UL').slideUp({ duration: o.collapseSpeed, easing: o.collapseEasing });
                            $(this).parent().removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed');
                        }
                    } else {
                        h($(this).attr('rel'));
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                // Prevent A from triggering the # on non-click events
                if( o.folderEvent.toLowerCase != 'click' ) $(t).find('LI A').bind('click', function() { return false; });
            }
            // Loading message
            $(this).html('<ul class="jqueryFileTree start"><li class="wait">' + o.loadMessage + '<li></ul>');
            // Get the initial file list
            showTree( $(this), escape(o.root) );
        });
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/ is broken

Comment: Try https://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I edited the code the same way as in the other StackOverflow question and it wasn't working. But the code above works perfectly fine.

All I had to do was to clear cache and rebuild my application, so that the old jqueryFileTree.js was updated.

Hope it helps