# JqueryFileTree - Get the last folder instead of the files

Tags: jquery

I'm using the JqueryFileTree plugin, and i'd like to get the last folder path instead of the files ones (I've guessed how to hide the file list in the .php file).

By the way, I tried to follow this : [Jquery File Tree - how to return folder name on folder click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000991/jquery-file-tree-how-to-return-folder-name-on-folder-click) but the console prints "dire is not a function"